# need to trigger a function without clicking mouse or using keyboard but using voice

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a java script function by voice over without using keyboard or mouse

```
function startDictation1(){
          var SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

          var recognition1 = new SpeechRecognition();

          var Textbox = $('#transcript1');
          var instructions = $('instructions');

          var Content = '';

          recognition1.continuous = true;

          recognition1.onresult = function(event1) {

            var current = event1.resultIndex;

            var transcript = event1.results[current][0].transcript;

              Content += transcript;
              Textbox.val(Content.toLowerCase());
  

              };

          recognition1.onstart = function() { 
            instructions.text('Voice recognition is ON.');
       }

          recognition1.onspeechend = function() {
            instructions.text('No activity.');
      }

          recognition1.onerror = function(event1) {
            if(event1.error == 'no-speech') {
              instructions.text('Try again.');  
            }
      }

          $('#btnx1').on('click', function(e) {
            if (Content.length) {
              Content += ' ';
        }
            recognition1.start();
      });

          Textbox.on('input', function() {

            Content = $(this).val();
      })}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. You haven't included any discernible question in your post; you've just dumped your code with little additional context. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could try running recognition.start() on page load.

```
var SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
var recognition1 = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition1.start();
```